# Change color of text in td based on value in Angular 6

Tags: css, angular6

I have a status column in my table
where I need to show different color text based on value. I am working using Angular 6.

```
<table>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Name</th>
<tr *ngFor="let data of data >
<td>{{data.status}}</td>
<td>{{data.name}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If the status is Pass and Approved, then the text is in green color,
If the status is failed and Error,  then the text is in red color,
If the status is a warning, then the text is in yellow color,
If the status is Ignored, then the text is in blue color,

Can anyone please help me how to do this in Angular 6.

Comment: [Dynamic styles in angular 6](https://v6.angular.io/api/common/NgStyle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can instantiate an array for corresponding colors:

Typescript:

```
colors = [{ status: "Passed", color: "red" }, { status: "Approuved", color: "red" }, 
                { status: "warning", color: "green" }, { status: "Ignored", color: "yellow" }]
```

Then you can use ngStyle to set the style dynamically:

**HTML**

```
...
<tr *ngFor="let row of data" [ngStyle]="{'background':getColor(row.status)}">
...
</tr>
```

were getColor is the following method:

**Typescript**

```
getTheColor(status) {
       return this.colors.filter(item => item.status === status)[0].color 
       // could be better written, but you get the idea
}
```

It return the color value based on status from the corresponding color array

That's it

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twvwpd)

Comment: Thank you. This is what i was looking for. @Vega

Comment: Very nice, I changed it to 

```return this.colors.filter(item => item.status === status)[0]?.color ?? 'black' ```

and it works perfect for my use case :)

Comment: Hi, I  tried to replicate the solution, but when trying in the browser it sends me the message::   re.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'color')

Comment: @Root93 because the filter returns 0 records. You can either try to change to ....[0]?.color (at the end), either check first the result length before taking color property. I hope this is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the mentioned angular dynamic styles, you could also have different spans with preset colorus that you choose from based on an `*ngIf` directive.

```html
<td>
  <span *ngIf="data.status == 'pass'" style="color: red">Pass</span> 
  <span *ngIf="data.status == 'approved'" style="color: green">Approved</span>
</td>
```